# How does the lives/hearts system work?

Tags: scurvy-scallywags

There are perhaps a couple of underlying questions here.  More specifically:

- What is the system for regaining lost lives (hearts)?  It seems you can buy them back (which I haven't tried) or collect a certain amount of band-aids (the number seems to increase each time you have to do it).  I'm assuming the cost of a heart also increases, so my question is: how do each of these numbers increase?
- What happens if you lose all your hearts?  I'm not sure I want to find out what happens, although it seems there are a few achievements geared towards it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 methods that I know of to regain hearts, and you mentioned both:

1. You can refill a single heart at the store. I've only ever seen them available for 5,000. You can only buy a single heart, and then you have to wait for the store to restock.
2. You can collect bandages to refill a heart. I think the first heart you lose, you have to collect 10 bandages, and then if you lose a second and third (you can have 4 total hearts I believe with an upgrade), you have to retrieve 15 bandages for those.

If you die, you have to start over. You keep your various upgrades and shanties, but you start back at the beginning of the map, so be sure to have plenty of upgrades on hand each board you play to be prepared to run if needed.

**EDIT:** It appears there is a way to revive yourself with gold if you have enough when you die, though I don't recall ever seeing this option.

Comment: I've only ever lost one heart at a time, so it seems the number of bandages simply depends on how many times it happens, or perhaps just something that increases while you play, e.g. your level?

Comment: Can I confirm, is that the beginning of the map, or just the current island?  Does that mean you start fighting very low-level enemies again?

Comment: @Matthew beginning of the entire map. It goes much quicker the second and third times around as you keep your upgrades.

Comment: @Matthew I clarified a few things. You drop to level 1, but keep upgrades when dying. Looked around, and apparently with gold, you can revive yourself, but i never saw this option. Not sure if it was added with an update or not.

Comment: Thanks.  I think we still have some unresolved questions about numbers of bandages, but this is all pretty helpful.